# Can creating indexes on MongoDB collections in a replica set be done programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I've seen the instructions for creating indexes on replica sets in MongoDB [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/build-indexes-on-replica-sets/). It looks fairly involved and requires the mongo shell. Is there an easier way and/or can this be done using C# MongoDB driver?

Comment: Have you done the **least** possible effort yourself? ie: type "mongodb c# driver ensureIndex" into google?

Comment: Um yes, hence the link to the documentation for creating indexes in MongoDB with a replica sets. I know how to do it with straight up mongodb but the instructions for replica sets seems to be far more involved.

Comment: And a down vote? seriously? Stackoverflow has become the playground of jerks.

Comment: It's not clear at all what you are asking for. Building an index on replica doesn't differ from building on standalone, unless you want to keep your replica set operational during long operation. You don't mention this though, complexity is your problem. And no - building index does not require mongo shell. Tutorial that you linked says *"Create the new index using the ensureIndex() in the mongo shell, or comparable method in your driver."*. It also describes steps that require restarting mongod and changing it's configuration, how do you want to do this via driver if your server is down?

Comment: So you basically answered my question and if you make a proper answer, I will mark it as such. This is far more helpful than your first comment. SO doesn't need to be so contentious. It is about helping which you have now done. Thanks.

Comment: To be clear, the documentation you linked for building indexes on replica sets is specifically to minimise the impact of building an index for a collection with a large set of data. If you aren't concerned about the potential impact of building indexes (for example, if the collection is empty or doesn't have much data) then you can ensure an index as normal (i.e. without additional complexity of doing a rolling index build).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/build-indexes-on-replica-sets/), there are 4 possible stages for both primaries and secondaries:

- Build the index in the background on the primary.
- Build the Index
- Stop One Secondary
- Restart the Program mongod

The first two you can do using the driver, because `mongod` is up. Use [`EnsureIndex`](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/1.1/html/3871579f-5b7c-1d9f-e66d-2403c9280e80.htm) with the right parameters.

For the next two you can't use the driver but you can still do programmatically as you would in a command prompt:

```
var stop = Process.Start("mongod", "--shutdown");
var standalone =  Process.Start("mongod", "--port 47017");
var replicated = Process.Start("mongod", "--port 27017 --replSet rs0");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this process to build a index on a replica set. Call it a "Rolling index build". For example assume you have 2+1 replica set

1. Take down the secondary from the replica set and add the index. Once the index is built you can bring it back up and let it catch up to the primary
2. Take down the primary and repeat the same process as 1.
3. You can decide if the old primary needs to become primary again or you are fine with the other server being primary.

Don't build the index on the background in the primary since it will be built on the foreground in the secondary (and this could take down the secondary). This behaviour is being changed in 2.6.